Ideal $\langle 3,x-1,y-2\rangle$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$
I am studying a little bit of ideals and come up with the exercise to show that the ideal $\langle 3,x-1,y-2\rangle$ is not equal to $\langle 1\rangle$ in the polynomial ring $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]$. At first sight, it seems like the elements $3,x-1,y-2$ cannot generate every polynomial. However, I've couldn't been able to find a rigorous proof. Any help will be appreciate it :).
Thanks in advance.

$\Bbb Z[x,y]/\langle 3,x-1,y-2\rangle\cong\dots\ne{0}$.

Isomorphic to...?

Try to find out! To warm up, prove that $\Bbb Z[x]/(x-a)\cong\Bbb Z$.

Hint: evaluate $1 = 3f + (x-1)g + (y-2)h,$ at $,(x,y)=(1,2),\Rightarrow, 1 = 3f(1,2)\Rightarrow 3^{-1}\in \Bbb Z.\ $ This is a duplicate so please delete it when all is clear. $\ \ $

...and then, that $\Bbb Z[x,y]/(x-a,y-b)\cong\Bbb Z$ (for any integers $a,b$).

Completing Anne Bauval's series of isomorphisms, $\mathbb{Z}[x,y]/\langle 3, x-1, y-2 \rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}/\langle 3 \rangle \not\cong {0}$.

Further (not needed), my prior comment shows an integer $,n\in I = (3,x!-!a,x!-!b)!\iff! \color{#c00}{3\mid n},,$ so the natural map of $,\Bbb Z,$ into $,R=\Bbb Z[x,y]/I,$ has kernel $,\color{#c00}{3\Bbb Z},,$ and it is onto by $!\bmod I!:\ f(x,y)\equiv f(a,b)\in\Bbb Z,,$ so $,R\cong \Bbb Z/\color{#c00}3,$ by the first isomorphism theorem. $\ \ $
